# A script for equalizing indentation in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

In some of the IDEs you can equalize the indentation of a selection of lines according to previous line indentation by some shortcut. Such a shortcut is Ctrl+I in Matlab m-file editor. I was wondering if there exist equivalent functionality for texstudio, or can it be implemented using javascript functionality of it.

- Revision:

I wrote the following script for the this task. However, it just correct one line. The question is how to include a block of lines also

```
%SCRIPT
l = cursor.lineNumber();
txt1 = editor.text(l-1);
txt2 = editor.text(l);
pad = txt1.match(/^\s+/);
txt2 = txt2.replace(/^\s+/,'');
if (pad == null)
    pad = ''
cursor.eraseLine(); 
cursor.insertText(pad+txt2+'\n', false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this. But yes, you can implement this by a JavaScript User Marco.